# How to open browser window and pass HTML content?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

By click on button "push" I need to open new window and pass to it HTML content to display it.

Here is view that display HTML:

[image]

Here is controller definition:

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$compile', '$scope','$window', function($compile, $scope, $window) {
    $scope.openWindow = function() {
        $window.open('to-print', 'width=500,height=400');
    };}]);
```

Here is HTML content:

```
<div ng-app="test" id = "content" ng-controller="testController">
<label>Entar Name:</label>
<label>Michael</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Entar Age:</label>
<label>25</label>
<hr/>
    <button ng-click="openWindow()">push!</button>
</div>
```

And the HTML I want to display inside opened window is:

```
<label>Entar Name:</label>
<label>Michael</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Entar Age:</label>
<label>25</label>
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/d8atdw0t/).

How can I implement it?

Comment: Please refer the below links. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553547/send-angularjs-variables-to-new-popup-window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921262/angularjs-issue-passing-data-to-a-new-browser-window-on-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple...
Add after

`.open()`

the following code

`.document.write("Lorem Ipsum");`

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/272/)

Comment: But how can I get html code from template in my controller?

Comment: Hey @Michael,
for example create a variable and put some html code inside.
See my example http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/273/

Answer (score 2):

You can include your content in **documet.write()** function

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "","width=600,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<label>Entar Name:</label><label>Michael</label><br/><br/><label>Entar Age:</label><label>25</label>");
    }
</script>
```